# A program about calculate the frequency of two students of a class have the same birthday

Tags: c, random

My problem is why the output at last is only 0 or 10000?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    int arr[30],i,j,k,res,num=0,flag=0;
    for(k=0;k<10;k++)     //the number of calculate
    {
        flag=0;
        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
        for(i=0;i<30;i++)
        {
            if((res=rand()%365)>32485)    //except the date bigger than 32485
                i--;
            else
                arr[i]=res%365;
        }
        for(i=0;i<29;i++)
        {
            for(j=i+1;j<30;j++)
                if(arr[i]==arr[j])
                {
                    flag=1;
                    break;     
                }
            if(flag==1)
            {
                num+=1;    //if find the same two,add number and break
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",num);     //why here is 0 or 10000 rather than other output?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `(res=rand()%365)>32485` always false.

Comment: thanks for your remind,it should be this:
if((res=rand())>32485）
but the problem is still there.@BLUEPIXY

Comment: Although code *can* speak for itself, I would prefer a short explanation of what results you expect? All you have said is what you DON'T expect, which does help us with commenting but leaves a lot of open ground. Please explain what you expect the output to be.

Comment: also, learn to **name things**. the only clue I get from `arr` is that.. well it's an array... `flag`, `num` and `res` is even worse.

Comment: absolutely the output should be a random number,it can't be 0 or 10000 every time when I run the program,I expect the output to have random-like,such as 7054,8065...And I have found the problem,that is:the srand statement should be out of all the loops,but I don't understand why.Just explain this to me is enough.@ nonsensickle

Comment: OK,but name a thing is really hard for me,but I will pay attention to this.@Karoly Horvath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator), you supposed to initialize it (`srand`) only once.

At the moment, you generate the same "random" number, again and again...

Note: instead of storing the days, store the counts for each day. It will give you a much cleaner code.

Also, learn to *name things*. variable names like `arr, flag, num, res` give almost zero clue about what those variables supposed to store. How about something more informative like `day`?

Answer (score 0):

> printf("%d\n",num);     //why here is 0 or 10000 rather than other output?

If you add some statement to output `arr` after you initialized it (after changed that `if((res=rand()%365)>32485)` to `if((res=rand())>32485)`, of course), you will find out you are using the same `arr` almost every time, because your iteration is so fast that it will finish far less that one second, so you are using the same random seed almost every time.

You could fix it by moving that `srand(..)` out of the enclosing `for` loop, do something like

```
srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
for(k=0;k<10;k++)     //the number of calculate
{
```

Comment: re-initializing a PRNG doesn't make it more random (quite the opposite). please don't do that.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yeah, put that statement before the `for` loop is a better fix. Thank you to put that out.

Comment: Sorry,the best answer should be yours but I had a wrong look

Comment: Sorry,lack of rep@leeduhem